# How to make simple Animation with React Native with onPress?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm working on a simple game with RN and just want to know how to make an object smoothly disappear after I click on it? I'm familiar mostly with hooks and wanted to know how to make it as simple as possible without using much "this" or classes or whatever. 
Please help me, I'll appreciate it very much! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Animated method takes parameters as values and turns those values into animated values then we can use those values to animate our Components:

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() =>this._start()}>
    <Text style={styles.textBtn}>Start</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <Animated.View
    style={{
      opacity: this.state.fadeValue,
      height: 250,
      width: 200,
      margin: 5,
      borderRadius: 12,
      backgroundColor: "#347a2a",
      justifyContent: "center"
    }}
  >
    <Text style={styles.text}>Fade </Text>
  </Animated.View>
</View>
```

Comment: Welcome My Friend

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `react-native-animatable` library.

one soluton:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({opacity:0})}>
  <Animatable.Text transition="opacity" style={{fontSize: this.state. opacity }}>Size me up, Scotty</Animatable.Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

the seconde solution

```
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

class ExampleView extends Component {
  handleTextRef = ref => this.text = ref;

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.text.transitionTo({ opacity: 0.2 })}>
        <Animatable.Text ref={this.handleTextRef}>Fade me!</Animatable.Text>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}
```

it has many configs, for more details, you can read the official [API](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable)

Comment: Thanks man! I just read it at the animatable docs and it' really awesome! But I got another small problem: I'm making a game where player has to guess the image by opening small parts of that image. The animation works perfectly fine but at the first render the animatable blocks are not rendered immediately but after about 1 second which make guessing the image useless as half of the image is already shown to the player. I wonder how could I delay rendering of that animatable block until fully loads and only then appear on the screen instead of appearing after 0.5s and showing part of image

Comment: I understand you want to start the animation after the view renders to finish, you can use it as the second solution, in the componDidMount to start the animation. if you want to delay the animation, you can use `dealy` props

Comment: Thanks! I actually used now Animated with hooks and it worked! This is great! :)